# Evolution process of eval(str) in python

Tags: python, eval

I find a code writen as follow:

```
nav_str = "'\\'!@34QWer\\''"
native_structure = eval(nav_str, {'__builtins__':{'set' : set}}, {})

>>> native_structure
>>> '!@34QWer'
```

I just wonder how `eval(nav_str, {'__builtins__':{'set' : set}}, {})` transfer `"'\\'!@34QWer\\''"` to  `'!@34QWer'`

**update**:
I have tried to understand `@user2357112`and `@Blender` for minutes,but I still can not realize this process.
As the answser,I think `eval("'\\'!@34QWer\\''")` should return `'\\'!@34QWer\\''`, but `'\\'!@34QWer\\''` is invalid.
What is the evolution process of `"'\\'!@34QWer\\''"` in eval()?

Comment: Can you post an actual REPL session? That code won't run.

Comment: You're not executing a `__builtins__` function at all. You are creating a custom `globals` that has nothing in it but a custom `__builtins__` that has nothing in it but the `set` function, but the string you evaluate doesn't use that function.

Comment: Whoever wrote that line of code was presumably trying to do something like `ast.literal_eval`, but that could also handle empty sets. Python's set literal can't handle empty sets; you have to write `set()`, which is not a literal. By doing a full `eval`, but in a custom environment where no names but `set` exist, you offer a way to create empty sets that's still somewhat safe. At any rate, you should definitely not be copying and using any code that uses `eval` without understanding what it means.

Comment: Of course, it's still not actually safe. Even with no globals or builtins whatsoever, you can still do [nasty things](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) with eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look at this part:

```
eval(nav_str, {'__builtins__':{'set' : set}}, {})
```

Normally, [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#eval) evaluates the expression you gave it in the normal environment, so these do the same thing:

```
>>> def foo(): print 'Hi'
>>> foo()
Hi
>>> eval('foo()')
Hi
```

But sometimes you don't want that. You probably don't want to take an arbitrary string off the web and `eval` it in your normal environment, unless you want to let people, e.g., `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')`. So, you can customize the environment the expression is evaluated in. The exact details are described in the docs above, but here's a quick example:

```
>>> def foo(): print 'Hi!'
>>> def bar(): print 'Bye!'
>>> eval('foo()')
Hi!
>>> eval('foo()', {'__builtins__': {}}, {})
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
>>> eval('foo()', {'__builtins__': {'foo': bar}}, {})
Bye!
```

So, why would you ever want an environment that has no names in it except for `set`?

Most likely because you wanted something like [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), but that also provided some way to handle empty sets. `literal_eval` only evaluates Python literals. But there is no literal for the empty set; you have to write `set()` instead. And `ast.literal_eval` can't handle `set()`. But the convoluted call to `eval` in your example can.

Of course this isn't perfect. Using `eval` allows all kinds of expressions that don't use names—math, list comprehensions, generator expressions, …

---

Now, let's look at the string you're evaluating:

```
nav_str = "'\\'!@34QWer\\''"
```

Well, there are no calls to `set` there. Or references to any names at all. So the extra complexity was just a red herring. You'd get the exact same thing with just `eval(nav_str)`.

So, what's the deal with that string?

Well, compare:

```
>>> print '\'!@34QWer\''
'!@34QWer'
>>> print eval(r"'\'!@34QWer\''")
'!@34QWer'
>>> print eval("'\\'!@34QWer\\''")
'!@34QWer'
```

The only reason you need

The only reasons it looks so complicated are that (a) whoever wrote the expression insisted on using single quotes even though the string itself has single quotes inside, necessitating backslash escaping, and (b) whoever wrote the code that stored the expression in a variable insisted on not using a raw string, necessitating doubling those backslashes.

You could write an equivalent expression with no backslashes:

```
>>> nav_str = '''"'!@34QWer'"'''
```

(It's not the *same* string literal expression, but it's a string literal expression that evaluates to the same value.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the contents of `nav_str`, without the string-literal escaping:

```
>>> print nav_str
'\'!@34QWer\''
```

These are the literal characters that `nav_str` contains. A single quote, a backslash, a single quote, an exclamation mark, etc. These characters form a valid Python string literal. `eval` evaluates the string literal, returning a string.

Comment: I have tried to understand this for minutes,but I still can not realize this process.As you say, I think `eval("'\\'!@34QWer\\''")` should return `'\\'!@34QWer\\''`, but `'\\'!@34QWer\\''` is invalid.What is the evolution process of `"'\\'!@34QWer\\''"` in eval()?

Comment: @Mithril: The string represented by the string literal `"'\\'!@34QWer\\''"` does not literally contain the characters between the quotation marks. A backslash in a string literal modifies the interpretation of the next character or characters, rather than literally representing a backslash. For example, in `\\`, the first backslash causes the second backslash to be interpreted as an actual backslash, so the string contains one backslash, rather than two.